# What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.User and HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I am currently working with some legacy code in which the `HttpContext.Current.User` property is used within an MVC controller method to perform some basic authorization on the current user. From reading the documentation there is also an `HttpContext.User` property and they both seem to indicate that they can get/set the current user. I'm curious if at some levels they are interchangeable and the same, or if there is a key difference between the 2 that would cause unintended issues in terms of authorizing or even recognizing the current user of the web application.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer to [`HttpContext.User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) directly, except perhaps inside of a controller. `User` is a property of the `HttpContext` class. You can do something like this:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
IPrincipal user = context.User;
```

that is, you can refer to the property through an instance of the `HttpContext` class.

The base `Controller` class has a property named [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext.aspx). Inside of a controller, if you reference `HttpContext.User`, you are referencing `base.HttpContext.User`, which will generally (always?) be the same thing as `HttpContext.Current.User`, simply because `base.HttpContext` will generally (maybe always?) be the same thing as `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx) sort of explains this (emphasis added, and although this is referring to web forms I believe the principle is the same in MVC):

> Because ASP.NET pages contain a default reference to the System.Web
> namespace (which contains the HttpContext class), you can reference
> the members of HttpContext on an .aspx page without using the fully
> qualified class reference to HttpContext. For example, you can use
> User.Identity.Name to get the name of the user on whose behalf the
> current process is running.
>
> However, if you want to use the members of
> IPrincipal from an ASP.NET code-behind module, you must include a
> reference to the System.Web namespace in the module and **a fully
> qualified reference to both the currently active request/response
> context** and the class in System.Web that you want to use
>
> For example,
> in a code-behind page you must specify the fully qualified name
> HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

Answer (score 1):

Both HttpContext.Current and HttpContext are the same as it's returning httpContext object for the current HTTP request.
But the later one is the property of the controller object, so it's available ONLY in a controller.